# SMTP SERVER for redirect mails in good dns

Tags: dns

I am a student, and i have a formation period.
They asked me to create a SMTP server/proxy for dispatch mails in one network with two DNS. In function of the domain of the receiver.
Example :

A is in DNS 1
B is in DNS 2

My server is out of this network , just like if i was in front of my house door and i tell to people coming in where they have to go, two choices ;).

I send an email to A, my server have to find in wich dns it is and send him well.

I just want that you tell me the steps i have to do. A tutorial would be so perfect .. :p

Sorry if there is languages mistakes etc ... i am french ;)

Answer (score 0):

i won't be doing your work :)  - but if I understand correctly your case, check "transports". Long story short - depending on recipient's domain (or even just mail address or so) your "proxy server" will forward mail to the proper destination mail server. You'll have to build a table of records with matching recipient/recipient domain and proper smtp server to forward email. Not sure what server exactly you want to use for it - or is it just some theoretical case. But anyway - Postfix does it in quite easy to understand way - so you may be good reading its manuals.

Comment: Ok, first thanks for your answer, you correctly understand, but i already know that, i know 'in big' what's server is, Mx , Mua , mta etc but i dont know how to do or to use it , i know the theory not the pratic ... :/, i grow up with windows, it makes only 2 years that i 'use' linux..

ReThanks for answered me

PS : why wont you do my work ? :)

Comment: To be perfectly honest - seriously try Postfix manuals. Postfix is easy to read/understand for human beings, and has quite approachable manuals, too. Anyway - just a quick one for now. mx - mail exchanger - domain's mail server, the one that accepts emails for the domain (it's still possible, that the architecture behind is more complex; it's not even said, that there has to be only one mx for each domain, there may be a number of those). mua - mail user agent, pretty much your mail program/client.

Comment: mta - mail transfer agent - well, pretty much also mail server, that accepts emails from your client, sends them further in the world, and also can receive emails from world for your account. Can be also your mx. And mx is also, pretty much, mta.

Comment: There can be also mda - mail delivery agent, lda - local delivery agent, and so on and so on - depending also on the terminology adopted in a particular product. Anyway - the subject can be quite complex, depending on chosen scenarios - mail servers are fairly flexible in that matter. But some general rules should be fairly simple. The basic logic has been presented in my first post. If you understand this logic - you should be able to present some solution. The question is what exactly you're meant to do? Bring some logical description or exact example based on specific mail server solution?

Comment: What may help you for start anyway - if you're completely fresh with it - maybe even reviewing searches done with something like: "how smtp works" or " how mailserver works" there's plenty of examples, also with some graphs, to present the logic of mail transportation.

Comment: yes since this morning i learned for all of this.

Comment: now i got a good idea of the thing , i will do this with emailrelay, good manual for it.

Comment: And that is thanks to you .. and a little for my mind too :p I will try now for 3h and come back tell you if i am crazy or if i won

Comment: You may find this quite useful (sticking to Postfix example)   http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Comment: Good luck - learning process isn't always easy, true that. But it will make you feel great when sorted! :)